# Looking for a CCTray Equivalent for GO

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net, cctray

Does anyone know of a CCTray Equivalent for Thoughtworks new version of CruiseControl.NET called GO?

Answer (score 5):

CCTray works with Go out of the box.

Just a few points to remember:

- the URL of Go's CCTray feed is included in the page footer in Go dashboard (the link is called `(cc) CCTray Feed`, you have to be logged in to see it),
- when adding the Go server to the list of servers in CCTray, choose `Supply a custom HTTP URL` and paste the feed URL,
- if the Go installation uses authentication, you can add your credentials in the URL, e.g. `http://USER:PASS@mygoserver/go/cctray.xml` (it works at least for HTTP Basic authentication, I have not tried other auth methods),
- don't enable `Server is secure` in server configuration in CCTray.

Answer (score 0):

According to ThoughtWorks' [product comparison](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/go-agile-release-management/feature-comparison), GO can send notifications through CCTray.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any kind of authentication then you will probably won't be able to get CCTray to work.

There is a utility developed that I found that does support ThoughtWorks Go through contacting ThoughtWorks support. You can find it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcctray/